# how to call an Iterator over a hashMap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

i need to see my hashMap keys and values in order to check if it s working properly.but im getting an error for the below lines:

```
Iterator iterator =  myHashMap.keySet().iterator();
    Flows flows = new Flows();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Object key = iterator.next();
        Object value = myHashMap.get(key); // <--
        //here is the error.  suspicious call to java.util.Map.get 
        //expected type Flows, actual type object

        System.out.println(key+" "+value);
    }
```

my keys are type of Flows and my values are FlowsStatics.

Comment: Don't use raw types in new code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: "suspicious call" isn't a compiler error.  It's perfectly legitimate in some situations (that's why it's only "suspicious"). What are you using that says it's an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iterator will automatically return objects of class Flows if you declare your `Map` as `Map<Flows, FlowsStatics>`, which you really should:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Flows key = iterator.next();
    FlowsStatics value = myHashMap.get(key);
```

Comment: Or typecast to "Flow" and "FlowStatics" if you haven't used generics.

Comment: yes this is my map: "final HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();"

Comment: You also need to declare the Iterator with a Type parameter in order for your answer to compile!

Answer (score 4):

Have you declared myHashMap using a Generic type: for example HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics> ?

If so, you should use Generics throughout:

```
Iterator<Flows> iterator =  myHashMap.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Flows key = iterator.next();
    FlowStatics value = myHashMap.get(key); // <--
```

or even:

```
for(Flows key: myHashMap.keySet().iterator()){
    FlowStatics value = myHashMap.get(key);
```

or even:

```
for(Map.Entry<Flows, FlowStatics> entry: myHashMap.entrySet().iterator()){
    Flows key = entry.getKey();
    FlowStatics value = entry.getValue();
```